# Joomla: How to get component (or module) variable from an other module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I'm working on a website using Joomla 2.5.6, Apache, and MySQL.

I have a page with an article in the main position, and I have another position on the side with customized content.

I need to get, for example, the title of the article in the module on the side. How can I do that? Can I retrieve from the custom module the same instance of the view or controller used for the article?

I need to know this so that I can create a sidebox with the article's title, anchors and specific links to video and PDFs related to the article displayed.

Comment: I'd use the module CSS selectors in JQuery to get all that information.

Comment: Finally, I used JFactory::getDocument().getTitle() for the title of the article (with is in fact the page title). Then, for the PDF and the video, I used, like you said, the CSS selectors of mootools. thx :)